# 2004 chevy cavalier- rolled backwards when in park, and not wont turn on

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, parking, cavalier

my car wont turn on. it rolls backwards when in park. and im not on a hill. its not the battery cause the radio and lights all turn on. i literally get a dead engine reaction when i turn the key. the Shifter feels like it lost resitanace and im able to move it freally and tooo easly

Comment: Just a guess but it sounds like the shifter is broken and the neutral safety switch is stopping the engine from starting, possibly because it's actually in gear rather than park

Comment: More than likely the shifter cable has broken.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a shift linkage problem.

The two pictures show where you need to check.

The first is easier to see.  The second requires removing the shift knob retention clip, the shift knob, and pulling the center console.

One of these two locations should reveal the problem.  It's possible something just "popped off" or came loose, and can be restored.  However, anything broken requires replacement of the entire shift cable assembly.

There's also a cable to engage parking; you can see it below the shift cable in the second picture.  There may be an issue here as well.

Good Luck!

[image]

[image]